# Extract only the <key> in plist using bash in Mac

Tags: linux, xcode, bash, macos, plist

I want to extract the key value in Countries in the following plist.
For example, I want the output file contains the following keys only:

```
USA
ITALY
```

But if I use the following script, It will print all the nested element under Countries including: 
           Capital
          Washington DC
           Continent
           North America.

How can I modify the script so that it will only print the keys under Countries?

```
output=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$infoplistPath/Info.plist" -c "Print :Nation:Countries")
```

Here is the plist:

```
<dict>
<key>Nation</key>
<dict>
   <key>Countries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>USA</key>
        <dict>
           <key>Capital</key>
           <string>Washington DC</string>
           <key>Continent</key>
           <string>North America</string>
        </dict>
           <key>Italy</key>
        <dict>
           <key>Capital</key>
           <string>Rome</string>
           <key>Continent</key>
           <string>Europe</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do with `PlistBuddy` directly, but with some tinkering, I was able to process the output to get what you want:

```
output=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$infoplistPath/Info.plist" -c "Print :Nation:Countries" | grep Dict | sed 's/^\(.*\) =.*/\1/g' | grep -v "Dict {" | awk '{print $1}')
```

When you echo the contents of `$output` it comes back with this:

```
$ echo $output
USA Italy
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I did it in a similar way as well.

Comment: `echo "$output" | awk '/= Dict/' | sed -e 's/= Dict {//g' `